# problema com folha de estilo no asp net

Tags: asp.net, css3

Eu uso o visual studio 2012. Estou trabalhando com asp net. Tenho uma folha de estilo dentro de uma pasta e a referencio numa página aspx. Quando crio uma nova tag html, um `<h3>` por exemplo, e faço modificações simples na folha de estilo como a cor do elemento, as vezes acontece dessa modificação não ser aplicada, ou seja, o `<h3>` fica com a cor padrão. Porém, se eu colocar o `<style></style>` e as modificações na própria aspx elas são aplicadas. Não importa se é por classe ou por id, isso as vezes anda acontecendo. Pra resolver, também posso copiar o conteúdo da folha de estilo que não está mais funcionando e colar numa nova folha de estilos. Estranho, não? Isso anda acontecendo com frequência, por que será?

Obs.: eu atualizava a página e até abria outra, mas o problema persistia, só resolvia conforme eu disse acima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é o Cache do browser. 
Quando acontecer isso recarregue à página usando ctrl + R.

Quando você acessa uma página, o browser salva os arquivos na memória para carregar mais rápido posteriormente. Então quando você recarrega a página ele pega os arquivos da memória em vez de pegar o que você editou.

Comment: Mas eu atualizava a página e nada acontecia e até abria outra pelo VS, persistia o problema.

Comment: Você atualiza com o 'ctrl + R' / 'ctrl + shift + R' ou F5 normal? por que quando você atualiza normal, com F5 ou pelo botão na barra do browser, o cache não é limpo. Os comandos que eu coloquei recarregam e limpam o cache da página.

Comment: Ok, eu recarregava com o f5 mesmo. Quando acontecer o problema vou fazer como disse.

Comment: Aconteceu o problema de novo, e realmente com o "ctrl + shift + r" resolveu. Obrigado, fera!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a respostas do Rafael, verifique se o arquivo css está setado corretamente, por exemplo:

```
<head>
<title>Exemplo</title>
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Outra questão é verificar se há outra `classe` ou `Id` de elemento de próprio CSS ou de outro, não esteja interferindo na propriedade que vocês queira alterar ou setar. Cabe lembrar, que você pode dar maior importância a propriedade, como segue:

```
.teste {background-color:#808080 !important;}
```